# C++ std::is_integral on lvalue and rvalue shows different results

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue, lvalue

I created a type validator to check whether a given argument is numeric.

```
template<typename T>
struct is_numeric
    : std::integral_constant<
        bool,
        std::is_integral_v<T> || std::is_floating_point_v<T>
    > {};

template<typename T>
inline constexpr bool is_numeric_v = is_numeric<T>::value;

template<typename T>
constexpr bool is_numeric_tuple(T&& value)
{ return is_numeric_v<T>; }

// variadic template implementation is omitted
```

Now, the problem is that

```
int i = 3;
is_numeric_tuple(3)  // returns true
is_numeric_tuple(i)  // returns false
```

And if I apply `std::remove_reference` to `is_numeric_tuple`, both results turn out to be true.

Does it mean that the STL implementation of `type_traits` like `is_integral`, `is_floating_point`, etc enforces given type to be rvalue?

And if so, why?

**UPDATE**:

As noted by **geza**, `type_traits` library I used only specifies a type itself, which means that

```
std::is_integral_v<int>;    // returns true
std::is_integral_v<int&>;   // returns false
std::is_integral_v<int&&>;  // returns false
```

The issue is not about either lvalue or rvalue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you're mixing up value category and types. These are strongly connected, but not the same.

`type_traits` needs a **type** parameter. It doesn't make sense to talk about rvalues here, as **expressions** has value category.

`is_integral` needs a non-reference type to return `true`. `is_integral_v<int &&>` (rvalue reference) still returns `false`, because it is a reference type.

In your first example (the literal `3`), `T` will be deduced as `int`, so is `is_numeric_tuple` will return `true` (as it is a non reference type).

In your second example, `T` will be deduced as `int &`, so it will return `false` (as it is a reference type).

Answer (score 0):

These type traits are meant to indicate different categories.  Every type falls under one of [these categories](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits#Primary_type_categories):

[image]

The type `int&` is a reference type, not an integral type.  Therefore, `is_integral` returns `false`.